# jax-rs: how to initialize an attribute in servlet context?

Tags: spring, jax-rs

I am currently using servlet context in my service:

```
@Context
private ServletContext servletContext;

public void aMethod(){
      servletContext.getAttribute(.. //this works
}
```

I'd like to initialize an attribute, but according to the documentation servlet context can only be accessed in web methods. I tried with:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    servletContext.setAttribute(... //this does NOT work
}
```

but it gives me null pointer exception.
How to solve this? I would like to avoid if null then.. schemas...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that when `@PostConstruct` methods are invoked the `ServletContext` is already available? If you need to use it in a service, try to inject it directly as a method parameter. Otherwise try with a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)